# PHP Warning Illegal string 'privacy_policy' in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I keep getting these PHP error warnings.

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'plugin_name' in /home/customer/www/website.com/public_html/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-privacy-policy-content.php on line 96

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'policy_text' in /home/customer/www/website.com/public_html/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-privacy-policy-content.php on line 97

The code is as shown below:

```
foreach ( $old as $key => $data ) {
            if ( ! empty( $data['removed'] ) ) {
                unset( $old[ $key ] );
                continue;
            }

            $old[ $key ] = array(
                'plugin_name' => $data['plugin_name'],
                'policy_text' => $data['policy_text'],
            );
        }
```

How do i fix this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a bug in one of the WP plugin's that you've downloaded. Turn off one plugin in turn and see which stops the error appearing to find which WP Plugin is the cause. The issue looks like something is passing a *non-array* value into a `$var` that is intended to be an array.

As [stated by Ro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64624959/3536236), it looks like the code is trying to process a *string* as an array. In this case there is an easy optout you can put into the code to ignore if it's not an array.

While this will solve your problem directly, I would **HIGHLY RECOMMEND** finding the source of the `$data` values and correcting the issue at source at that point (as stated, probably in a plugin).

```
foreach ( $old as $key => $data ) {

    if(!is_array($data)){
        continue; // if data is not an array then 
                  // carry on to the next iteration.
    }
    if ( ! empty( $data['removed'] ) ) {
            unset( $old[ $key ] );
            continue;
        }

        $old[ $key ] = array(
            'plugin_name' => $data['plugin_name'],
            'policy_text' => $data['policy_text'],
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `$data` is in fact a string rather than an array. Accessing a string in the way that you do will result in 'Warning: Illegal string offset' in PHP versions prior to 8.0.0beta.

See [this eval](https://3v4l.org/T3bPP).